# Why do all input feilds now have a blue outline after installing flowbite?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, flowbite

I recently installed flowbite-react to my react app and now all input fields across my whole app have a blue outline when focused. Even when I apply styles to remove the outline, nothing seems to work.

Everything installed properly and I added the config and plugin to tailwindcss.

Is this an issue anyone has encountered?

Here is a screenshot of inspecting the element:
[image]

I found this style when inspecting the element:
--tw-ring-color is the issue
[image]

I tried adding this to index.css it made the outline smaller but it is still there

```
* {
    --tw-ring-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0) !important;
  }
```

Kyle Xyian Dilbeck solution below works for the Flowbite wrapper. If you want to add an inline style do this:

focus:border-transparent OR a color of your choice, the blue ring will be removed

the ring inline class still does not remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You've done nothing wrong*** and it is working as expected!! When you install a UI lib like flowbite then their default styles are applied.

---

### Explanation

The blue outline you're seeing is due to the **default focus styles** applied by Flowbite-React or Tailwind CSS. One way to remove this outline is by using the outline-none utility class provided by Tailwind CSS or more specifically **changing the `ring` style. If you add ring-0 it should effectively remove it. [You can also see this link for other colors and options for tailwind css ring color.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/ring-color)**

---

### Solutions

Because flowbite uses tailwind css we will update the tailwind style. It is currently applying the style via 'ring color' which you can change in a few ways, here are two main examples(which are recommended by [flowbite docs](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/customize/theme)):

### Inline Example

ex. 1: change to red

```html
<input className="ring-2 ring-blue-500 focus:ring-red-500" type="text" />
```

ex. 2: remove it completely

```
<input className="ring-0 focus:ring-transparent" type="text" />
```

**Above** is the first option offered by flowbite react. **Below** is the second where you can create a custom theme - [see documentation here](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/customize/theme).

### Theme Example:

Remove ring color from all inputs in a component via [flowbite theme wrapper](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/customize/theme)

```
import type { CustomFlowbiteTheme } from 'flowbite-react';
import { Flowbite } from 'flowbite-react';

const customTheme: CustomFlowbiteTheme = {
  input: {
    ringColor: 'ring-transparent focus:ring-transparent',
  },
};

export default function MyPage() {
  return (
    <Flowbite theme={{ theme: customTheme }}>
      <input className="ring-2 focus:ring-2" type="text" />
    </Flowbite>
  );
}
```

---

PS:

If it works then don't forget to mark your question as answered!

Also if you liked my solution and think it shows good research, I'd appreciate the upvote!

Comment: I tried both ways and the outline is still there :(

Comment: could you inspect the element, look at the input and then post the picture or code? if you imported the css in a component using inputs then this should definitely override it

Comment: Added a screenshot of the inspection

Comment: keep playing with the inspect until you find exactly where that blue outline is being applied - once you do this i can help you override it (see my example on how to add styles via inspect)

Comment: Appreciate you helping man. I just added a screenshot of a style I found when inspecting further. Can I override this?

Comment: i updated the answer, after further testing i noticed its all styled via tailwind so you can change it via tailwind classes more easily! Thank you for updating the picture it helped me realize it was ring color for tail wind css

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Flowbite overrides all input fields' focus outline color in the DOM. If you want to stop it, you have to override the CSS property of outline in all input fields with the "important" keyword.
Make sure your CSS styles are applied to DOM. if it's not applying means CSS is not imported correctly.

Try inline CSS and set outline to None.

```
input:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

Without Focus,

```
input{
  outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This still does not remove it :(

Comment: What is the input fields you have used, Is it Metetial UI Testfield?

Comment: No, just a html input field

Comment: Ok then, try this. 
input{
  outline: none !important;
}

Comment: Still nothing unfortunately

Comment: when you inspect the input that has the border, try overriding it in the inspect by using the checkboxes for its attributes or try to override it by saying border 1px red !important....if you can see the red border then we know we are in the right place, but if you cannot then maybe we need to apply this to a different class or element attribute